# Cant fix: java.io.NotSerializableException at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, bukkit

I have an issue with `java.io.NotSerializableException  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)`. Here is the important part of the code.

```
public class PlayerConfigAccess implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //some load and create methods

    public static void saveFile (File file, Player player)
    {
    Object object = (Object) PlayerConfigContent.getContent(player);

    if(!existFile(file))
    {
        createFile(file);
    }

    try{

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        PlayerConfigContent.remove(player);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

The object I am about to save is a `PlayerConfig` custom thing, that I convert back to `Object`.
The method gets the file that should be saved when its called, I made sure it exists, so there cant be the problem.
Does someone know who I can fix this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html. When you send something via snail mail, what is the object that must fit in an envelope? The object you send, or you, the sender of the object? When you save an object to a file, what must be serializable, the object you save, or the class saving the object?

Comment: The problem is that `PlayerConfig` is obviously not serialzable (does not implement `Serializable`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that you're actually writing needs to be serializable, not the class that is actually holds the writing code. What object type does `PlayerConfigContent.getContent` return?

Comment: So I have to add `implements Serializable` to the `PlayerConfig` class?
It returns a `PlayerConfig` that has been stored in a HashMap temporarily.

Comment: Yes the PlayerConfig class is what needs to be serializable, not the PlayerConfigAccess

Comment: Once you do that, change `Object object = (Object) PlayerConfigContent.getContent(player);`

 to  `PlayerConfig object = PlayerConfigContent.getContent(player);` and it should work